# Trying pass a C code for Python, bus have a error IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, c

I have a code in C and I'm trying to pass it to python, I'm having a lot of problems and I've already researched the hotspots but so far unsuccessfully. I will be posting the code in C and what I did in Python, please help me

Code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define Tam 3

int main (){

int R[Tam + 2];
int G[Tam + 2];
int B[Tam + 2];

float Rf[Tam];
float Gf[Tam];
float Bf[Tam];

float dist[Tam];

int i;
float soma = 0;

R[0] = 0;
R[Tam + 1] = 0;
G[0] = 0;
G[Tam + 1] = 0;
B[0] = 0;
B[Tam + 1] = 0;

printf("insira os valores RGB no formato R,G,B\n");

for (i = 1; i <= Tam; i++){
    scanf ("%d,%d,%d", &R[i], &G[i], &B[i]);}

for (i = 1; i <= Tam; i++){

    Rf[i - 1] = (R[i-1] + R[i] + R[i+1])/3;
    Gf[i - 1] = (G[i-1] + G[i] + G[i+1])/3;
    Bf[i - 1] = (B[i-1] + B[i] + B[i+1])/3;
}

for (i = 0; i < Tam; i++){
    dist[i] = sqrt(pow(R[i + 1] - Rf[i], 2) + pow(G[i + 1] - Gf[i], 2) + p 
pow(B[i + 1] - Bf[i], 2));
    }

for (i = 0; i < Tam; i++){
    soma = soma + dist[i];
    }

soma = soma / Tam;

printf("media da distancia euclidiana = %.1f", soma);


return 0;
}
```

And here, the code in Python:

```
from math import sqrt

Tam = 3
soma = 0

R = [Tam + 2]
G = [Tam + 2]
B = [Tam + 2]

Rf = [3]
Gf = [Tam]
Bf = [Tam]

dist = [Tam]

R.insert(0, -1)
R.append(0)

G.insert(0, -1)
G.append(0)

B.insert(0, -1)
B.append(0)

# for i in range(0, -1):
#     R[i] = 0
#     G[i] = 0
#     B[i] = 0



print("insira os valores RGB no formato R,G,B: \n")

for i in range(1, 2):
    R.append(int(input()))
    G.append(int(input()))
    B.append(int(input()))

for i in range(1, Tam):
    Rf[i-1] = (R[i-1] + R[i] + R[i+1])/3
    Gf[i-1] = ((G[i-1] + G[i] + G[i+1])/3)
    Bf[i-1] = ((B[i-1] + B[i] + B[i+1])/3)

for i in range(0, Tam):
    dist.append(sqrt(pow(R[i+1] - Rf[i], 2) + pow(G[i+1] - Gf[i], 2)))

for i in range(0, Tam):
    soma = soma.__add__(dist[i])

soma = soma/Tam

print('Média da distância euclidiana = ', soma)
```

And show this error:

```
File "exer1.py", line 40, in <module>                                                                                     
Rf[i] = (R[i] + R[i+1] + R[i+2])/3                                                                                  
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I wanted to understand what I can do as a match in python because I know I'm using some wrong syntax

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, you need to extract a [mcve] from your code, which also ensures that it's not an error you could easily solve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can `try/except` any attempts to retrieve an index:

```
for i in range(1, Tam):
    try:
        Rf[i-1] = (R[i-1] + R[i] + R[i+1])/3
        Gf[i-1] = ((G[i-1] + G[i] + G[i+1])/3)
        Bf[i-1] = ((B[i-1] + B[i] + B[i+1])/3)
    except IndexError as ex:  # this line may need to change, based on your python version 
        # printing will at least let you know the error happened, without blowing up                
        print(str(ex))  
        pass
```